# How to expand Container color widget, without children, in Row / Column?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to fill the remaining space in a `Row` with a `Column`  using a `Container` widget? I have tried using `Expanded` but the container will not take up available space.

The desired `Row` design is similar to this:

[image: Desired design with filled container]

In my app, this `Row` is wrapped in a `Column` and the `Container` is not filling space when using `Expanded`.

[image: Sample app screenshot without filled container]

Sample app:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            const Text("Some text"),
            Row(
              children: [
                const Text("Flutter"),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(color: Colors.pink),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const Text("Some more text"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As shown in the sample app, the expanded container does not show with its pink background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping the row with IntrinsicHeight.

```
 Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      const Text("Some text"),
      IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            const Text('Flutter'),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      const Text("Some more text"),
    ],
  ),
```

[image]